# How to list all installed software in terminal by recent date installed?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

Sorry, probably asked before but I can't seem to find.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
zgrep -i "status installed"  /var/log/dpkg* | sort -t- -k1 -k2 -k3 -n > temp.txt
```

`zgrep` allows you to examine archived `dpkg` logs as well. For example, I see:

```
$ ls /var/log/dpkg*
/var/log/dpkg.log  /var/log/dpkg.log.1  /var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz  /var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz  /var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz
$
```

And then the output is piped to `sort` where

- `-t-` specifies `-` as the field delimiter
- `-k1`, `-k2` and `-k3` tell sort to use those fields in sequence
- `-n` ensures a numerical sort.
- `>` directs the output to a text file because the output can run over several hundred lines

See `man sort` for more such as `-r` if you wish to reverse the order.

What I see with the `zgrep` command on my system (with several lines deleted):

```
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2018-04-26 18:17:44 status installed base-files:amd64 10.1ubuntu2
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2018-04-26 18:17:44 status installed base-passwd:amd64 3.5.44
...
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2018-05-02 18:21:13 status installed linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic:amd64 4.15.0-20.21
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2018-05-02 18:21:56 status installed grub-gfxpayload-lists:amd64 0.7
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2018-05-02 18:21:56 status installed grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8
...
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2018-06-01 05:29:41 status installed netcat-openbsd:amd64 1.187-1ubuntu0.1
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2018-06-01 05:29:43 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2018-06-02 13:59:20 status installed libkf5kmahjongglib-data:all 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1
...
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2018-07-01 06:32:51 status installed ncdu:amd64 1.12-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2018-07-01 06:32:52 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2018-07-02 07:20:02 status installed libastro1:amd64 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1
...
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-08-01 06:19:16 status installed chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 68.0.3440.75-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-08-01 06:19:16 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-08-01 06:19:18 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2
...
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-08-31 07:14:09 status installed libx11-data:all 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-08-31 07:14:09 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-08-31 07:14:10 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
```

A limitation of this approach is that, ultimately, some archived files will be deleted depending on how `logrotate` is set up. Look at fiddling with `file:///etc/logrotate.d/dpkg` and, of course, `man logrotate`.